# What would be the opposite of this function to find 14bit value from two 8bit values?

Tags: c#, function, logic, bit-manipulation

The following takes two 8bit integers and combines them to generate a 14bit integer.

```
    public static int CombineBytes(int LSB, int MSB)
    {
        int _14bit;

        _14bit = MSB;
        _14bit <<= 7;
        _14bit |= LSB;

        return(_14bit);
    }
```

What would be the opposite process to this function?

For example if I supplied a function with a 14bit integer I would get two 8bit integers in the form of the most significant byte and the least significant byte?

Comment: Do you mean two 7 bit integers?

Comment: Definitely 8 bit.  Range must be [0, 127] or 128 possible values and therefore 2^8 or 8bit.

Comment: 0 to 127 requires only 7 bits. 8 bits would be a full byte, and thus the range from 0 to 255. `2^7 = 128`, `2^8 = 256`

Comment: Tired and not thinking would be my excuse.  I'll attempt to implement your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean two 7 bit integers, you can get the high 7 bits by shifting 7 to the right `high = combined >> 7` and the low 7 bits by masking with binary and `low = combined & 0x7F`.